# match something not followed AND preceded by something

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to match every "e" char, that is not part of the Scientific e notation (e.g. 3e+6) surrounded by brackets. I can do the opposite without problems: `/(?<=\(\d)e(?=[+-]\d+\)/)`
The problem is, that if I try to do it (`/(?<!\(\d+)e(?![+-]\d+\))/`) it doesnt matches as soon as either the first or last part doesnt match (not and).

In short it should match the e in:

```
23e+4
4e
e
e+5)
(4e
```

but not in:

```
(23e+5)
```

(or match any e that isnt matched by this `/\(\d+e[+-]\d+\)/`)

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your original pattern is

```
\(\d+e[+-]\d+\)
```

To invert that sort of logic, you can alternate between:

- negative lookbehind for `\(\d+`, followed by a match for `e`, and
- a match for `e`, followed by negative lookahead for `[+-]\d+\)`:

```
(?<!\(\d+)e|e(?![+-]\d+\))
```

https://regexr.com/4v3sg

Answer (score 0):

A non regex solution can be something like this

1. Check if the string starts with `(` and ends with `)` then return false
2. If not then check whether it has `e` in it or not return boolean value accordingly

```js
let arr = [`23e+4`,`4e`,`e`,`e+5)`,`(4e`,`(23e+5)`]

let checker = v =>
  v.startsWith('(') && v.endsWith(')') ? 'false' : v.includes('e')

arr.forEach(v => console.log(checker(v)))
```